# Do I need to install bower components each time I create project

Tags: angularjs, bower, webstorm

Do I need to install bower components each time I create angular project in WebStorm?

I created 2 projects and installed bower components separately each time. I believe there must some other method for this.

[image: As soon as I create new project I get the project structure as below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each project should have own dependencies, isn't it? The main idea of a frontend package managers is "setup all dependence locally".

Frontend a bit different from a backend, so You may read this article [Bower: Why Front-End Needs a Package Manager](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/bower-why-frontend-package-manager/) to understand why things so.

Another idea of bower - is to keep in vcs(git, etc) only **bower.json**. When another man from you team download the project, he should to do the only thing - make `bower install` and bower will download all dependencies for this project only (he didn't want to know about your other projects)

There is no point to install deps one time for all project, cause this is a frontend, not a backend.

One of the best practice for frontend - is to concat all .js and .css files for one huge javascript file (and one for css).
In common way when you do this, you should specify project js dirs.
I belive these big files should be uniq for each project.

P.S. But if you still want to use bower in *global* way, you may specify bower's setup dir in `.bowerrc` file:

```
{
    "directory" : "../my_global_libs"
}

```

And setup your projects to look into. 
(And you may do concat with this lib, take a look for grunt or gulp)